# Limit Structure Depth

Tags: structure

Is it possible to limit the number of levels within a Structure element?

Let's say for example, I only want to max of two levels. So there can be only have something like the following with no way to allow a child of a child so to speak:

- Parent

  - Child
  - Child
- Parent

  - Child
- Parent
- Parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in to the structured section's settings (Settings->Sections->Structure Name)) and set the "Max Levels" property.

Comment: You beat me to it by 4 seconds. Go and further improve Craft, you.

Comment: All I'm doing today is breaking things. :)

Comment: Yes, my 1500 points total today, for instance ;) This whole 'getting-points-for-answering-questions' thing is getting pretty addictive :S

Comment: Ugh, stared at that setting so many times and brain kept saying, that's max entries. Ready for some t-day time off. Thanks @BradBell

Comment: @PaulVerheul It's what is so great about SE! And no worries, SethG.